# Migration not working, undefined method `fetch'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have the following migration, where I try and add two new column and then update all records to have the new default values. But alas this isn't working as intended. instead I get the error: `undefined method 'fetch' for :boolean:Symbol`

```
class AlterPostsTableAddPublishedAndSaved < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def change
    add_column :posts, :saved, :published, :boolean, :default => 0
    Post.reset_column_information
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up { Post.update_all saved: false, published: true }
    end
  end
end
```

According to [what I have read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-existing-migrations), I believe I am going about this the right way. Could some one shed some light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be done in two steps, and 0 is not a value for boolean, have to use true or false.

```
add_column :posts, :saved, :boolean, default: false
add_column :posts, :published, :boolean, default: false
```